# Velusia Sample - Redirect after Registration

Tags: openiddict

In the sample "Velusia" provided here [Github OpenIdDict-Samples](https://github.com/openiddict/openiddict-samples), upon most of the action the user is redirected back to the client, however upon the registration, the user is sent to the server 'home/index' page. How can I make it send a user same as the login action, back to the client?

We do have the ability to specify the SignOut redirect uri, however there is no visible option for Sign In

I could as well add in a home controller for index view a redirect to my app, however i would loose the uri I started with and would have to probably redo the request

[image]